# Multiple using block, is this code safe?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, using, idisposable

Code snippet is as follows

```
 public static string ToCompressedBase64(this string text)
    {
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var gZipOutputStream = new GZipStream(memoryStream, CompressionMode.Compress))
            {
                using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(gZipOutputStream))
                {
                    streamWriter.Write(text);
                }
            }
            return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
```

As far as I know, if class contains field which is IDisposable then It should implement IDisposable itself and take care of disposal of the owned object, so with this assumptions, after disposal of streamWriter the gZipOutputStream and memoryStream will also be disposed. But we still need not disposed memoryStream to invoke toArray() method on It.
So the question is, Is calling ToArray() method on memoryStream at the end safe?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to call it at the end? I'd call it immediately following the streamWriter.Write.

Comment: @Kevin The `GZipStream` might not have processed all the data after calling `StreamWriter.Write`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking if it's safe to call `ToArray()` on a `MemoryStream` after it has been disposed.

If so, then yes, it's safe. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx) specifies:

> This method works when the `MemoryStream` is closed.

**EDIT**: And in case it's not clear whether `closed` also means `disposed`, you can also look at the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/stream.cs,f1b4285950a82354) for the `Dispose` method (Note: The link is to `Stream.Dispose()` since `MemoryStream` doesn't override the `Dispose` method):

```
public void Dispose()
{
    /* These are correct, but we'd have to fix PipeStream & NetworkStream very carefully.
    Contract.Ensures(CanRead == false);
    Contract.Ensures(CanWrite == false);
    Contract.Ensures(CanSeek == false);
    */

    Close();
}
```

As you can see, calling `Dispose()` does nothing more than calling `Close()`.

Comment: Closed or disposed?